# how to prevent dc from breaking the output

Tags: bash, dc

I'm using the "dc" command to convert from Hexadecimal to Decimal

```
dc -e "16i$1p"
```

The problem is that it breaks the output on large numbers

```
795717178255658627448611597034913344160729841275756347904742363029055\
1952200534008528895
```

How do I prevent this behaviour? Is there an option or argument to pass to disable this?

Comment: Add `| tr -d '\\\\\n'`

Answer (score 0):

bc seems to do the same thing.  The 70 characters limit is listed in this spec as well:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/bc.html

Off the top of my head, just postprocess:

```
echo "ibase=16; FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF" | bc | perl -pe's/\\\n//'
```

Other options are suggested here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/how-can-you-combine-all-lines-that-end-with-a-backslash-character

Answer (score 0):

The question is old and cold, but I think it appropriate to note that on newer versions of both GNU `dc` and `bc`, this feature can be disabled via environment variables

```
n=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
n+=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

DC_LINE_LENGTH=0 dc -e "16i${n}p"

BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc <<<"ibase=16; $n"
```